# How to generate Columns of table by Using Aggregate Function in Crystal reports?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dataset, aggregate-functions, crystal-reports-2008

I want to Generate crystal report using a Table.

This Table has 4 columns whose values are generated by performing `SUM()` function along with `WHERE` clause on another table.

How can I get these `SUM()` field as columns?

Schema of table is aas follows:

```
 MainTable(pk,Amount,Mode)
 DataTable(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4)
```

Here

```
Column1 = SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE Mode = 011
Column2 = SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE Mode = 012
Column2 = SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE Mode = 100
Column2 = SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE Mode = 030
```

I am not getting how to generate DataTable so that to use it in Crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

No need 2 genrate table just go through crystal report cross tab wizard.

Comment: Can we create more than 1 column using same aggregate function on a particular field(i.e Amount field)of another table using different filters?